# why all subsequent arguments should have default values once a default value is provided?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, default

can anyone tell me that once i declare a default argument in c++ function, then why should all the subsequent arguments should have default values
? I know

Comment: You say "I know," so why do you need someone to tell you?

Comment: sorry, i wrote that by mistake. i was in a hurry at that time.